# OpenCV FileStorage empty after loading

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Im trying to load a string into filestorage. I will not have the file to pass filename as a parameter to load it. Instead I recive an xml document as a string. In the doc http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html#filestorage it is mentioned that source attribute of fs.open can be "text string to read the data from". I run some simple tests with OpenCv CascadeClassifier as a string but I get an empty FileStorage. What am I doing wrong?

```
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;

std::ifstream t("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
std::string ClasifierInString((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

cout << ClasifierInString << endl; //I CAN PRINT THE FILE AND SEE IT

cv::FileStorage fs;

if (!fs.open(ClasifierInString, cv::FileStorage::READ | cv::FileStorage::MEMORY | cv::FileStorage::FORMAT_XML))
{
    cout << "Couldn't load file into memory" << endl;
    return -2;
}

FileNodeIterator it = fs.getFirstTopLevelNode().begin(), it_end = fs.getFirstTopLevelNode().end();
for (; it != it_end; ++it)
{
    cout << (string)*it << "\n"; //EMPTY LINE????
}

if (!face_cascade.read(fs.getFirstTopLevelNode()))
{
    cout << "Couldn't read file from memory" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

EDIT:

@sop can't comment yet. Maybe your using older version of OpenCV. I have the file and I am able to load it with:

```
face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
```

and it works. The problem is I'm unable to read it as a string with face_cascade.read(string)

Comment: you can only read cascades generated by opencv_traincascade this way, not older(haar) cascades generated by the older haartraining tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@berak comment is the correct answer. I used `lbpcascade_frontalface.xml` as this is new cascade (and is faster! :) Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the file name: `"haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"`. There is no such a file in the OpenCV flder... Try `"haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml"`.

Here is my code that works:

```
cv::CascadeClassifier face_cascade;

std::ifstream t("haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");
std::string ClasifierInString((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

std::cout << ClasifierInString << std::endl; //I CAN PRINT THE FILE AND SEE IT

cv::FileStorage fs;

if (!fs.open(ClasifierInString, /*cv::FileStorage::READ | */cv::FileStorage::MEMORY | cv::FileStorage::FORMAT_XML))
{
        std::cout << "Couldn't load file into memory" << std::endl;
        return -2;
}

cv::FileNodeIterator it = fs.getFirstTopLevelNode().begin(), it_end = fs.getFirstTopLevelNode().end();
for (; it != it_end; ++it)
{
        std::cout << (std::string)*it << "\n"; //EMPTY LINE????
}

if (!face_cascade.read(fs.getFirstTopLevelNode()))
{
        std::cout << "Couldn't read file from memory" << std::endl;
        return -1;
}
```